# How to use IPv6 address in telegram socks proxy?

Tags: proxy, ipv6, telegram, socks

I'm trying to make **Telegram** work with my socks5 proxy.
It works with **ipv4** addresses well, but if i put **ipv6** address of the same container, it can't connect.

It seems, that **ipv6** addresses are interpreted as domain names, and Telegram is not connecting to them. It seems, that checkbox "Try connecting through ipv6" has no effect.

How can I make Telegram recognize an ipv6 address and connect to a proxy that way?

I'm doing that on **Windows Desktop Telegram application**.

**UPD**:
I tried `[2a03:b0c0:2:d0::d32:1]`, `2a03:b0c0:2:d0::d32:1` and  `http://[2a03:b0c0:2:d0::d32:1]` but had no luck with that.

Comment: Did you follow _[RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)_?

Comment: I tried both with and without "[ ]" if that's what you mean.
[2a03:b0c0:2:d0::d32:1].
I copied the address directly from my container's page on DigitalOcean.